# Drawing a filled shape in front of a line with even odd rule?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, fill, shapes, scoping

What I am trying to do is to draw a filled shape in "front" off a vertical line, to give the effect that the line is "behind" the shape. I think it involves the even odd rule but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\fill[gray,opacity=0.5,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was quite confused. What do you want achieve? Maybe show some schematic of the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

The shapes are drawn in the order, that is in your code. `even odd rule` has nothing to do with this. Your circle is in front of your line. Your circle is transparent.

Maybe you do not wish for your circle to be tranparent:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\fill[gray] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A line and a gray circle]